# Portugese layout is partially incorrect

Tags: 11.10, keyboard-layout

I upgraded to Oneiric Ocelot, and the Portuguese layout is partially incorrect. How can i correct this?

Comment: After restarting the machine, the problem seems to have been solved.

Answer (score 2):

*Answered by OP in a comment*

> After restarting the machine, the problem seems to have been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Setting keyboard layouts in 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot is really no different from doing it in 11.04 natty Narwhal. Go to System Settings and you will find Keyboard Layouts and Language Support utilities.

If you have tried this and it did not work then you should have supplied that information as of part of your question.

Comment: I think that by referring that a particular keyboard layout (Portuguese) was incorrect, it was implied that I had already chosen a layout, and it wasn't working as expected.